# Upper and lower variation of a complex measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, soft-question

This question is similar to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2429129/why-is-the-total-variation-of-a-complex-measure-defined-in-this-way), but I didn't understand the answer.

In [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation#Total_variation_norm_of_complex_measures), is said that

> If the measure $\mu$ is a complex measure, its **upper** and **lower** variation cannot be defined.

Why is it necessary to define in a different way the total variation of a complex measure? Are the two definitions equivalent if it is a signed measure?

Answer (score 1):

There is no notion of inequalities for complex numbers. So the notions of supremum and infimum don't exist in $\mathbb C$ and upper and lower variation cannot be defined for complex measures.

For a signed measure the two notions are equivalent. Ref: Rudin's RCA.