# If $f$ is real-valued bounded measurable and $\mu$ a complex measure, then $\left | \int_X f \mathrm d \mu \right | \le \int_X |f| \mathrm d |\mu|$

Tags: integration, measure-theory, inequality

Let $(X, \mathcal X)$ be a measurable space. Let $\mu$ be a [complex measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_measure) on $X$ and $|\mu|$ its [variation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_measure#Variation_of_a_complex_measure_and_polar_decomposition). Then $|\mu|$ is a non-negative finite measure. By definition, $|\mu(B)| \le |\mu| (B)$ for all $B \in \mathcal X$.

Let $\mu_1, \mu_2$ be the real and imaginary parts of $\mu$. Then $\mu_1, \mu_2$ are finite [signed measures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_measure) such that $\mu = \mu_1 + i \mu_2$. Let $(\mu_1^+, \mu_1^-)$ and $(\mu_2^+, \mu_2^-)$ be the [Jordan decompositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn_decomposition_theorem#Jordan_measure_decomposition) of $\mu_1, \mu_2$ respectively. Then $\mu_1^+, \mu_1^-, \mu_2^+, \mu_2^-$ are non-negative finite measures such that $\mu_1 = \mu_1^+ - \mu_1^-$ and $\mu_2 = \mu_2^+ - \mu_2^-$.

[Integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_measure#Integration_with_respect_to_a_complex_measure) w.r.t. $\mu$ is defined as follows.

- If $f:X \to \mathbb R$ is measurable then
  $$
  \begin{align}
  \int_X f \mathrm d \mu &:= \int_X f \mathrm d \mu_1 + i \int_X f \mathrm d \mu_2 \\
  &:= \left [ \int_X f \mathrm d \mu_1^+ - \int_X f \mathrm d \mu_1^-  \right ] + \left [ \int_X f \mathrm d \mu_2^+ - \int_X f \mathrm d \mu_2^- \right ], \quad (\star)
  \end{align}
  $$
  provided that each integral in $(\star)$ is well-defined.
- If $f:X \to \mathbb C$ is measurable then
  $$
  \int_X f \mathrm d \mu := \int_X (\operatorname{Re} f) \mathrm d \mu  + i \int_X (\operatorname{Im} f) \mathrm d \mu.
  $$

In a proof of [this result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4572315/let-x-be-locally-compact-separable-and-mu-n-overset-rightharpoonup-mu), I appealed to below inequality many times.

> **Theorem:** If $f:X \to \mathbb R$ measurable bounded, then
> $$
> \left | \int_X f \mathrm d  \mu \right | \le \int_X |f| \mathrm d |\mu|
> $$

As such, I would like to prove it. Could you have a check on my attempt?

---

**Proof:** For convenience, let $\alpha$ be the value of the LHS and $\beta$ that of the RHS.

1. Let $f = 1_B$ with $B \in \mathcal X$. So $f$ is a characteristic function.

We have $\alpha = |\mu(B)|$ and $\beta = |\mu| (B)$. The claim then holds.

2. Let $f = \sum_{i=1}^m b_i 1_{B_1}$ with $b_i \in \mathbb R$ and $B_i \in \mathcal X$ such that $B_i \cap B_j \neq \emptyset \iff i=j$. So $f$ is a simple function.

We have $\alpha = |\sum_{i=1}^m b_i \mu(B_i)|$ and $\beta = \sum_{i=1}^m |b_i| \cdot |\mu| (B_i)$. The claim then holds thanks to triangle inequality and (1.)

3. Let $f:X \to \mathbb R$ be measurable bounded.

There is a sequence $(f_n)$ of simple functions such that $(f_n)$ is *uniformly bounded* and that $f_n \to f$ pointwise *everywhere*. By applying [DCT](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4298588/dominated-convergence-theorem-for-banach-space) for each term in $(\star)$, we have
$$
\alpha = \left | \lim_n \int_X f_n \mathrm d  \mu \right | = \lim_n \left |  \int_X f_n \mathrm d  \mu \right | .
$$

By (2.), we get
$$
\alpha \le \lim_n \int_X |f_n| \mathrm d  |\mu|.
$$

By DCT again, we have
$$
\lim_n \int_X |f_n| \mathrm d  |\mu| = \int_X |f| \mathrm d  |\mu| = \beta.
$$

This completes the proof.

Comment: For a reference, @DavidC.Ullrich gave an elegant proof based on the polar decomposition of a complex measure [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1567729/1019043).

Comment: (+1) Once you have the (real version) Radon-Nikodym theorem at your disposal, it is easy to get a complexificaton of it and see that $d\mu=h\,d|\mu|$ with $|h|=1$ using   the definition of variation measure. This will simplify your proof considerably. Since you are interested in complexification of *operators*, I think [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4572386/121671) may be interesting to you

Comment: Also, [this](https://www.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:999179/FULLTEXT01.pdf) Bachellor's thesis has some interesing nuggets